# Change "yith woocommerce wishlist" template folder

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Anyone know if is possible to change the folder where the plugin "Yith WooCommerce wishlist" load their templates, I intend to change some html.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

you can override it by putting the file template "wishlist.php" inside the "woocommerce" folder of the theme folder.

You could find the answer here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-wishlist/faq/

Just make sure you create a woocommerce folder inside your child theme and place it in there.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I changed the default woocommerce folder. Using add_filter( 'woocommerce_template_path'...)

Comment: Hello, i put the wishlist-view.php in the woocommerce folder of my child theme but it doesn't override

Answer (score 0):

copy **yith-woocommerce-wishlist-> templates** folder
paste in **woocommerce folder**